# How can i override this css behavior with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following html:

```
 <div class="card">
 <span class="cardDropdown">
    <img class="cardDownArrow" src="/Icons/arrow_down_white.png"/> 
 </span>
</div>
```

and the following css so normally this img is hidden unless you over hovering the outer card

```
.card:hover .cardDropdown 
{
    visibility: visible;
}

.card .cardDropdown 
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

There is a certain situation where during an ajax call i want to show this image even if i am not hovering over the card.  How can i override this

```
 visibility: hidden;
```

setting just during this specific set of jquery code and have it go back to normal after my ajax call ends?

Comment: just access directly to the `.cardDropdown` and set its `visibility` to `visible`

Comment: You can use add.class and remove.class of jquery. Check this link http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an new rule to your CSS that will override the others because it comes after and has appropriate specificity:

```
/* default value is hidden */
.card .cardDropdown 
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* show on hover */
.card:hover .cardDropdown 
{
    visibility: visible;
}

/* always show the card if .cardShow class is present */
.card.cardShow .cardDropDown {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

And, then add that `.cardShow` class to your card object when you want the visiblity to persist, then remove that class when you want it to go back to the dynamic behavior:

```
// make visiblity persist regardless of hover state
$(theCard).addClass("cardShow");
```

and

```
// restore dynamic behavior based on hover
$(theCard).removeClass("cardShow");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `cardImage.style.visibility = 'visible';` (assuming `cardImage` is a reference to the DOM element in question). This will override CSS set in the stylesheet.

Then set `cardImage.style.visibility = '';` to let the stylesheet take hold again.

Answer (score 0):

Just not to overcomplicate, add or remove `cardDropdown` class when required:

```
$('.card > span').addClass('cardDropdown');     // show
$('.card > span').removeClass('cardDropdown');  // hide
```

... if you have no other styles defined for `cardDropdown` class, otherwise just use different class name.